# Android 4.0 Next function from keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

On my edit text I put the keyboard to have the "Next" button. The problem is that when the Next button is pressed on Android 4.0 (I tested on Emulator and on a device with Android 4.0) the cursor places at the beginning of the word instead of at the end of the word. What should I do?

NOTE: On my Motorola Defy (Android 2.2) it's working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the onFocusChangeListener for the editText, and when the focus changes do something like this to set the cursor to the end of the text

```
editText.setSelection(editText.length - 1);
```